# How to post a post on Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I want to post on Facebook a result like this:

[image: expected]
"**User_name** posted a post on **App_name.**"

I have tried with  "/feed" but result return is:

[image: result]

"**User_name** updated his status."

I don't know how to return result as expected above ?

Comment: That is your activity log. Why do you want something there?

Comment: I'm want posting result like this:
"**User_name** posted a post on **App_name.**"
not 
"**User_name** updated his status.""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm want posting result like this: "**User_name** posted a post on **App_name**."

That would be a [custom Open Graph story](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom), where the verb is "posting" and the object is "post." But since posting a post is a "native" Facebook action, I don't even see how they got that through review.

Anyway, custom OG stories [are deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom-open-graph-deprecation), so you can't use them in new apps any more, and they will be removed for existing ones soon.

If you have a valid use case for the [common actions and objects types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph), then you can post a story using those.

Otherwise, just make a normal post, and accept that it looks like posts do.